# How can I create a mapView

Tags: react-native

I try to create a MapView, but when I enter the page containing it I get an error.

```
<View>
    <MapView style={{ flex: 1, height: 500 }}
         zoomEnabled={false}
         scrollEnabled={false}
         initialRegion={{
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
          >
         <Marker
            coordinate={{ latitude: 37.78825, longitude: -122.4324 }}
            title={'title'}
            description={'description'}
         />
    </MapView>
</View>
```

[image: My error]

Comment: Have you link the maps?

Comment: No, I'm using .expo

Comment: Can you show the full file with imports?